# LWJGL Display.update() automatically capping FPS to 60

Tags: java, lwjgl, frame-rate, game-loop

I am trying to get my game's FPS to go to e.g. 100 and even though I correctly call

```
Display.sync(100);
```

The FPS is 60..

Main loop looks like this:

```
int delta = this.getDelta();
this.update(delta);
this.drawGL();

this.updateFPS();

Display.update(); // Automatically caps FPS to 60--unwanted
Display.sync(100); // And yet FPS is 60
```

I should add that completely removing `Display.sync(100);` makes no difference to the FPS..

Comment: What happens if you call `Display.setVSyncEnabled(false)` before entering the game loop?

Comment: I forgot to say VSync is disabled.. (happens during initGL()). having tried calling `Display.setVSyncEnabled(false);` at the beginning of the loop doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is machine-specific. Running on different machine solved it.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that Display.setVsyncEnabled(true) isn't anywhere in your code, if you don't have that anywhere, check in your graphics driver settings, sometimes people have force vsync to on in there.

Comment: That could be it.. I will check with my other computer today. On laptop right now